# Overload tuple indexing operator - C++

Tags: c++, indexing, tuples, operator-overloading, std

How can I overload indexing `[]` operator for `std::tuple<int,int,int>`? So when I have `std::tuple<int,int,int> tup` and I type `tup[0]` I want it to return the reference to `get<0>(tup)`. Is this possible?

Comment: Why not to use `std::array<int,3>` instead?

Comment: Hello! Can you elaborate on why you want to do this? If you need to lookup tuple elements by index at runtime, you likely don't want to be using a tuple.

Comment: I was just wondering if it was possible, I know about overloading input and output operators, but wanted to know indexing operator overloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers - it is not possible to add any member function to `std` type like `std::tuple`. And `operator[]` has to be non-static member function.

But you can wrap this tuple - and add `operator[]` to this wrapper type. In such case - you would need to know the common return type for all elements of tuple. Well - there is std::any which can work for most of types.

This should work, but this is only to meet your curiosity - it would be bad design to use something like that in real software:

```
template <typename Tuple, typename ReturnType = std::any>
class TupleExtractor
{
public:
    TupleExtractor(const Tuple& tuple) 
        : TupleExtractor(tuple, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>>{})
    {}
    
    ReturnType operator[](std::size_t index) const
    {
        return extractors[index](tuple);
    }

private:
    template <std::size_t I>
    static ReturnType get(const Tuple& tuple)
    {
        return std::get<I>(tuple);
    }


    template <std::size_t ...I>
    TupleExtractor(const Tuple& tuple, std::index_sequence<I...>) 
        : tuple(tuple), 
          extractors{&TupleExtractor::get<I>...}
    {}

    const Tuple& tuple;
    using Extractor = ReturnType(*)(const Tuple&);
    std::vector<Extractor> extractors;
};
```

and test - that it works:

```
int main() {
    std::tuple<int, int, int> a{1,2,3};
    TupleExtractor e{a};
    
    return std::any_cast<int>(e[2]);
}
```

Comment: Typo: `using Extractor = ReturnType(*)(const Tuple&);`

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for 2 reasons:

1. `operator[]` must be a non-static member function, and since you're not implementing the standard library, you can't add a member function to `std::tuple`.
2. The index must be a constant expression, which you can't enforce with function arguments.